# Class diagram for nodejs?

Tags: oop, node.js

I am looking into node.js. I am slowly "getting there". However, I have a question.
Is there a "diagram" to figure out the hierarchy of classes?

I realise that a socket is an EventEmitter but also a Stream and... well, is there an easy-to-read diagram to figure out what is what?

Comment: No, but you can read the documentation and the code. The "class hierachy" in node is thin, so you shouldnt need a diagram

Comment: Hummm I still wish it were out there. I think it would be useful, as thin as it is.

Answer (score 3):

I made a module that generate a class diagram for javascript/node/html/css. Its based on the "WAE" extension of UML. Its called wavi. For javascript, function,variable and use of other modules are 
automatically recognized.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/wavi

[image: Diagram generated by wavi]

Comment: My question is actually about documenting node itself, more than node programs!

Comment: Ok, well if its not in javascript it won't work, it really depend on the language, id try using reverse engineering option with a uml tool from node.js source code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is the best answer I could find:

https://github.com/nsyee/node-objects-diagram/blob/master/node-objects.png

Unfortunately the node-objects-diagram script doesn't seem to want to work with the latest node. So, it's showing an old (see: obsolete) version of node.

But, maybe this is a good start?